# How long will a meeting room's status change from "no response" to "accept" When use EWS API to create a meeting

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I use Appointment.Save API to create a meeting. And check the status by type get appointment.Resources[0].ResponseType.
I want Exchange can tell me the "accept" response as soon as possible, but some times it takes almost 1 minute 30 seconds to get the "accept" response.

I want to know what is the longest time that the meeting room's status change from "no response" to "accept" When use EWS API to create a meeting

my source code sample is:

```
Appointment appointment = new Appointment(exchangeService);
appointment.Resources.Add(<meeting room mail address>);
appointment.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendOnlyToAll);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how predictable this will be because it depends on several factors:

- Size of the Exchange environment (CPUs, disks, etc.)
- Or whether this is O365 and how busy it is
- How many meetings are currently in the accept process among how many rooms.

Because the accept process involves a workflow within the Exchange services, unless one knows the internals of that process, I doubt you can come up with anything beyond a best guess.